# floating point error gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, floating-point-exceptions

I am trying to debug a Fortran program. To catch floating point errors, I'm using the following compiler options for gfortran 4.9.0:

```
FFLAGS1 = -std=f2003 -ffree-form -fdefault-real-8 -fdefault-double-8  \
          -Ofast -fall-intrinsics -fcheck=all -m64 \
          -fno-trapping-math -c \
          -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,underflow,precision,denormal -Wall
```

With these options, the program fails at this line:

```
read(ctrlUnit,*) slope_fasst, aspect
```

when trying to read these inputs: 10.0 70.0

If I remove

```
-ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow,underflow,precision,denormal
```

from the compiler options, it reads the following line just fine. Both variables are declared as `real(8)`. In the input file, I've tried spaces, commas, etc. but see no changes. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: What error does the run-time system report ?  And what is the program trying to read when it fails ?

Comment: I'm trying to read these inputs: 10.0 70.0

Comment: Are those the only inputs that are being read?  That's somewhat interesting, in that `10.0` and `70.0` *are* exactly representable in either single- or double-precision IEEE 754 floating-point, so it must be errors that occur *during* the conversion process that trigger the trap.  Ideally, the conversion from string would only set the inexact flag if the final result is not exactly representable.

Comment: If @user2417662 comes back maybe he can tell us the compiler version.

Comment: Yes, those are the only numbers being read in. The compiler version is gfortran 4.9.0.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the gfortran `-ffpe-trap,precision` flag results in errors for perfectly normal / routine read/write operations.

For example, this program throws a "Floating exception" error:

```
    write(*,*)1.0
    end
```

(gfortran 4.1.2, redhat linux)

Solution, do not use that flag.

Note this makes sense since the conversion from machine number to/from ascii results in a loss of precision ( I'm not sure if thats the intent of the flag to catch such though )

Comment: Yes, `precision` sounds like it must correspond to the usual IEEE 754 "Inexact" trap.  Since many many floating-point operations can give inexact results, including conversion from string, I'd imagine that a typical program using floating-point would be unusable with that flag set.

Comment: gfortran 4.1.2 is from 2007.   It is a very old version, early in the development of gfortran.   My opinion: don't use any version before 4.4.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Indeed "precision" corresponds to the IEEE 754 inexact exception. This was fixed in 2011, nowadays gfortran instead uses "inexact", (while keeping "precision" as an alias for backwards compatibility).

Comment: I took out precision and it made no difference.

Comment: try removing the flags one at a time to see what the cause is.  ( And posting the exact error message might be useful )